# Agendar e cancelar tarefa em Node.JS (node-cron, cron ou schedule)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduler

Criei um servidor simples com duas rotas, uma para iniciar um serviço periódico 
`/job/start` e outra para cancelá-lo `/job/stop`.

Eis o código:

```
// framework
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// router
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/job/:order', (req, res) => {

    // função a ser executada periodicamente
    const periodicFoo = () => console.log('__PERIODIC_FOO__');

    // configuração do cronograma
    const cron = require('node-cron');
    cron.schedule('periodic-foo', '*/3 * * * * *', periodicFoo);   
    const job = cron.getTasks['periodic-foo'];

    // inicia ou cancela o cronograma
    switch (req.params.order) {
        case ('start'):
            job.start();
            res.send('Job Start');
        break;
        case ('stop'):
            job.stop();
            res.send('Job Stop');
        break;
        default:
            res.send('Job no order');
        break;
    }
});
app.use(router);

// running
app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Server running!'));
```

Dependências do `package.json` para fins de teste:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "cron": "^1.8.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2"
  }
```

Como podem ver, eu já testei várias bibliotecas [`node-cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), [`cron`](http://npmjs.com/package/cron) e [`node-schedule`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule).

Mas todas sem sucesso.

Vejam esse artigo no StackOverflow: [How to stop a node cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684668/how-to-stop-a-node-cron-job).

É legal, mas também não funcionou.

Então é isso.

Eu quero criar um servidor com uma rota para inicializar um job que rodaria indefinidamente & periodicamente e uma outra para cancelar essa tarefa.

Como posso fazer isso?

Obs: Criar a tarefa é fácil. O difícil é abrir uma nova aba no navegador (isto é, uma nova instância do servidor Node) que corresponda àquele mesmo job da outra instância, a fim selecioná-lo e cancelá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, sei que o tópico ta aberto a bastante tempo, mas passei por algo parecido e encontrei uma solução que pode lhe ajudar.

Eu utilizei a lib [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) e fiz o seguinte:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

//scheduleList vai ser a lista de processos que você criou utilizando a lib
const scheduleList = schedule.scheduledJobs;
//processName vai ser o nome do processo que você vai passar na hora que criar um processo utilizando a lib
if (scheduleList['processName'] != undefined) {
    //Nesse caso, caso ele ache o nome do processo na lista vamos utilizar o nome dele para cancela-lo.
    scheduleList.processName.cancel();
}
//Aqui vou criar um processo
const currentDate = new Date();
//scheduleDate é a data qual o processo vai rodar, neste caso apos 1 minuto da data em que esse script foi chamado
const scheduleDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 1 * 60000);

schedule.scheduleJob('processName', scheduleDate, function () {
      console.log('Acabamos de criar um novo processo com o nome de processName');
    });
```

Nesse exemplo você consegue ver como criar um processo utilizando a lib [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), como listar os processos criados através dela e como cancelar um processo utilizando o nome que lhe foi dado.